# "Subject to Change" Usage

Tags: phrases

I have the following sentence:

> (...) these dates are subject to change.

Should that, instead, read:

> (...) these dates may be subject to change.

Are only one of these usages correct?  I want it to be interpreted to mean that the dates may change.  (but they may not necessarily change)

My guess is that we're working with the following definition of `subject` (from dictionary.com):

> 19: (Adjective) open or exposed (usually followed by to): subject to ridicule.

I think that would make the first quote valid.  But how about the second?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's start here.

> Subject: Likely or prone to be affected by

So, let's see that phrase with the definition instead of the word.

> These dates may be prone to changing.

So this means that there is uncertainty as to whether or not the dates could change.

However, the phrase

> These dates are subject to change.

Indicates that you know the dates could change, and that they might.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking.

Comment: I think that's being a bit too literal. It's true you can logically define a difference *from the writer's point of view* between not knowing whether the dates are capable of being changed at all, and not knowing whether they will in fact be changed even though you know that's a possibility. But this makes no difference to the *reader*, who's only concerned with the fact that there is some uncertainty. In practice, adding **may be** is a device for implying (truthfully or otherwise) that change is less likely. Just as **will be** implies *more* likelihood.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I considered exactly that, and you may be right, but I asked a few people near me and they seemed to think that adding the *may be* was redundant. However, I think you're point has plenty of merit.

Comment: I agree that *may be*, *will be*, etc., are to all intents and purposes redundant in this context. As is *and purposes* (and probably *to all intents*) in that sentence. Do such devices convey any meaning at all? Are they 'just' euphemisms, and does that classification itself imply meaninglessness? I really don't know.